# How to configure IIS for to make ASP.NET MVC intranet app work correctly?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with a auto-authorization using the client's windows logon username.

When I run the app in the VS web server, it works perfectly. It starts on a random port (as usual) and immediately accepts any HTTP request, passing to the web server my windows username correctly (with a computer name as well).

When I deploy this project onto the IIS 7.5 I cant access the website in any way - I have been changing the authentication options and got no result - either IIS infinitely asks for credentials or displays "Error, No Access" page.

So, what options do I need to configure to let anyone correctly open the site, providing the credentials automatically?

Comment: What auth mode have you set? And what want to use? Using AD/NTLM/Kerberos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable Windows authentication in IIS for your website.

Comment: You also need to disable Anonymous Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the site to use Windows Authentication from within your web.config file under the `<system.web>` tag like so:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>
```

This will be picked up by IIS which will then set the Authentication mode to Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Windows Authentication just enable it on IIS and disable other types. Keep in mind that it'll automatically work only under Internet Explorer and Chrome. Opera and Firefox will ask for credentials.

Also one problem I feel you might have is actually testing it in built-in web server. While it's functional it does not handle authentication exactly as you would expect. Even when you enable NTLM and website authenticates you it still uses anonymous authentication in some places.

I would suggest to deploy and test such website not on built-in server but on local IIS. It's easy to setup directly from VS, you just have to enable it if you don't have it already in Windows. Also keep in mind to setup authentication in IIS correctly.

Good luck!